# С#. Использование закрытых элементов в классах-наследниках

Tags: c#, ооп, наследование

Доброго времени суток участники форума. Столкнулся с проблемой при изучении языка C#. Интересует вопрос: почему при наследовании из производного класса мы можем использовать закрытые поля (обозначенные именно private модификатором) через публичные методы, унаследованные от базового класса. Я думал, что такие поля в наследовании не участвуют и соответственно в производном классе их нет. Оставлю в качестве примера код ниже:

```
namespace Inheritance
{
   class BaseClass
   {
      private int a;
      public int A
      {
         get
         {
             return a;
         }
         set
         {
            a = value;
         }
      }
   }
   class DerivedClass : BaseClass
   {
   }         
   class Program
   {
      static void Main()
      {
         DerivedClass instance = new DerivedClass();
         instance.A = 3;
         Console.WriteLine(instance.A); // 3
      }
   }
}
```

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: A и a - суть разные вещи. вот так попробуйте DerivedClass instance = new DerivedClass();
         instance.a = 7;и всё поймёте

Comment: @Konst но 'A' оперирует полем 'a'

Comment: это уже у вас экземпляр класса

Comment: Как я понимаю, наследуемый класс не наследует поле, а просто неявно создаст за счёт сеттера для себя такое же приватное и будет работать с ним

Comment: @СергейМишин, спасибо! Жду еще мнений :)

Comment: Нет, вы не можете использовать закрытые поля и другие закрытые члены родительского класса. Создайте, например, контструктор или любой метод в DerivedClass и попробуйте обратиться к `a`. Не получится.

Comment: В сеттере свойства `A` может происходить запись в файл или в базу данных, а в геттере - чтение оттуда. Но производный класс об этом не узнает.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, но в геттере же происходит запись в "несуществующую" переменную. Как по мне, должно было быть что-то вроде исключения :)

Comment: [Спецификация C#](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/classes.md#inheritance): Instance constructors, destructors, and static constructors are not inherited, but all other members are, **regardless of their declared accessibility**.

Comment: @PetSerAl Хороший ответ, спасибо! Теперь, если я правильно понял, наследование приватных полей предполагает не их удаление в классах-наследниках, а запрет на их использование при реализации своих методов в классах-наследниках?

Comment: @NepoSSEDA Вы вполне можете их использовать, если у Вас есть к ним доступ: https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQiDMACA3u7Q7RBPAoigIQDoARbAE2wF5soBTAd2xtoAoAlAG5yFQg2oBJFtgAsCEWjFE4SAJx8Jk4aOwBfdAYw5EPMkqIAHMAEsAbgENg7bDajBXiinBOlaIM3wLZR9Xd2xpIOVlAHN2D2YAPk9daOwAZ3iWZJsZRwAbCHYvaKMKIyMgA==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наследование предполагает расширение базового класса. При расширении и речи быть не может, что будет теряться хоть какая-то часть базового класса. Следовательно, производный класс будет иметь все поля и методы базового класса, включая приватные и защищенные. Если бы что-то из этого не наследовал ось, то работали бы публичные методы без реализации класса (приватных полей и методов)?

Разница в том, что из производного класса нельзя обращаться напрямую к приватным полям, но это возможно с использованием геттеров и сеттеров базового класса.

Comment: Уже разобрался, но все равно большое спасибо за ответ! Помечу верным ответом на заметку другим людям :)